# $E \to S$ surjective in degrees $\geq 1$ implies $\widetilde{E} \to \widetilde{S}$ surjective

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, proof-verification

In the proof of Theorem II.8.13 in Hartshorne (which is the Euler sequence), the author writes:

> Let $S = A[x_0, \ldots, x_n]$. [...] The exact sequence
>   $$0 \to M \to E \to S$$
>   of graded $S$-modules gives rise to an exact sequence of sheaves of $\mathbb{P}^n_A$,
>   $$0 \to \widetilde{M} \to \widetilde{E} \to \mathcal{O}_X \to 0.$$
>   Note that $E \to S$ is not surjective, but is surjective in all degrees $\geq 1$, **so the corresponding map of sheaves is surjective**.

Hartshorne doesn't give any justification for this last statement.  I've come up with a justification which I *think* holds, but I haven't seen it written down anywhere and I don't quite trust myself to do commutative algebra, so, two questions:

1. Is the following result true, and its proof valid?
2. Is this the intended justification?

---

**Proposition.** Let $S$ be a graded ring, $M = \bigoplus\limits_{d=0}^\infty M_d$ a graded $S$-modules, and $$\bigoplus\limits_{d=n}^\infty M_d \subseteq N \subseteq M$$ a graded $S$-submodule.  For each $\mathfrak{p} \in \operatorname{Proj} S$, we have $N_{(\mathfrak{p})} = M_{(\mathfrak{p})}$.

**Proof.** Write $T$ for the set of homogeneous elements in $S \setminus \mathfrak{p}$, so that $S_{(\mathfrak{p})} = (T^{-1}S)_0$, $M_{(\mathfrak{p})} = (T^{-1}M)_0$, and so forth.  Clearly $N_{(\mathfrak{p})} \subseteq M_{(\mathfrak{p})}$.  Consider an element $\frac{m}{t} \in M_{(\mathfrak{p})}$. Since $S_+ \not \subseteq \mathfrak{p}$ we can find some homogeneous $v \in S_+$ with $v \not \in \mathfrak{p}$.  Then $v$ is both an element of $S$ of positive degree and a unit of $T^{-1} S$.  It follows that $mv^n$ must have degree at least $n$, so $$mv^n \in \bigoplus\limits_{d=n}^\infty M_d \subseteq N.$$
Consequently,
$$\frac{m}{t} = \frac{m v^n}{t v^n} \in N_{(\mathfrak{p})}.$$

---

As a corollary, any map of $S$-modules that was surjective in sufficiently high degree would necessarily  induce a surjective map of sheaves on $\operatorname{Proj} S$.

Comment: Yes, that's fine, you're heading towards Serre's description of $\text{Coh}({\mathbb P}_{\mathbb k}^n)$ as the quotient of ${\mathbb k}[X_0,...,X_n]\text{-grmod}$ by the Serre subcategory of finite length modules! :)

Comment: In Hartshorne's defense, Ex. 5.9c and some reasoning about quasicoherence would take care of this too.

Comment: Dear Daniel, this is not correct: $v$ does not belong to $S_{(\mathfrak{p})}$ because it doesn't have degree $0$ and so is certainly not a unit in $S_{(\mathfrak{p})}$.

Comment: Ah.  Yeah, that's annoying.  What I meant to say is that $v$ is a unit in $T^{-1} S$, where $S_{(\mathfrak{p})} = (T^{-1}S)_0$.  I've updated the question to correct this.